# Is there a place to get sample printed circuit boards?

Tags: pcb

I'm planning on building a project, but it involves me probably using some circuit boards. Most if not all of my parts that I have I got from SamTec, who gives free samples of different kinds of connectors, etc. All in all is there a way to get (free) sample PCB's?

Comment: You can purchase custom boards at any number of sites for 10 bucks shipped. That's multiple copies of 2x2" boards for super cheap. Seeed, itead, etc.

Comment: I have gotten sample boards for free. Just build up a legitimate history of placing large repeat orders and manufacturers will take care of you.

Answer (score 3):

Free sample PCBs are very unlikely, as the fabrication process is somewhat expensive and time-consuming. However, you can get prototype boards very cheap from [OSHpark](https://oshpark.com) or [DirtyPCBs](http://dirtypcbs.com/). They'll make you a small batch of boards for just a few dollars each (depending on the size).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean custom PC boards designed for a particular project, then it is extraordinarily unlikely that anybody would make something free. Unless you can convince them that you will be buying thousands of them per month.

If you mean a generic perf-board, then that is a commodity part like any other, and you should be able to use similar methods to ask for free samples.

There are several quite low price custom PC board vendors available online, but virtually all of them require manufacturing time of several weeks.

There is an online service that compares pricing from dozens of vendors: http://pcbshopper.com/